# Where is the Magento 2 update/cron.php file supposed to come from?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I have installed Magento 2 using the instructions in the development documentation.

Everything works fine except for the cron jobs that the admin system continually says are not working.

I followed the development docs and added the following lines into my crontabs file.

```
*/1 * * * * php -c /etc/php5/cli/apache2 /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run 
*/1 * * * * php -c /etc/php5/cli/apache2 /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php 
*/1 * * * * php -c /etc/php5/cli/apache2 /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

I have manually run the first and third command and they run without error. The second line I am having problems with. `/var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php` does not exist. In fact the `update` directory does not exist.

Where does the `update` directory come from, and why don't I have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update/cron.php` file is in the `magento2-community-edition` package:
https://github.com/magento/magento2-community-edition/blob/2.0.0/update/cron.php

Comment: I'm confused. The repo the docs say you should clone is the `magento/magento2` repository. I haven't seen any mention of the `magento/magento2-community-edition` repo in any of the docs.

Comment: You don't have to clone the repository. You have [other options](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/continue.html). But if you do clone the GitHub repository, you have to perform [additional steps](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/prereq_updater.html) to get the updater to work

Comment: I'm re-installing using the first option on your "other options" link. Are there any docs listing which directories I'll need to copy over to my new copy of Magento?